# What is the minimum of learning to say Kaddish d’Rabanan?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, kaddish

What is the minimum amount of study one has to learn or hear in order to say Kaddish d’rabanan? Is there a certain Halacha which states how much or what is the minimum one needs to learn?

Also, a side point, would reading an aggadic passage out loud to a group of Jews that don’t understand what it means classify as “learning” in order to say this Kaddish?